# Dell R710 possible to change form factor?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I can't seem to get a straight answer about this question.

I recently purchased a used R710, but I  misread the description for the form factor and received the 8 x 2.5" SAS configuration.

I want to keep my existing RAID disks (4 x 2TB 3.5).

Is it possible to change the drive configuration to a 6 x 3.5 ? If so, which components would I need to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd be better off selling it on again, and buying the right one.  I think changing the form factor is likely to be difficult, because the metalwork is physically a different shape for the drive bay slots, isn't it?

Comment: I would like to keep this server, as it has the controller, memory, and CPUs I want. The solution may be to just buy a barebones model with form factor and swap everything into that.

Comment: As cheap as they are now, buying another one, swapping parts out, and selling on the leftovers should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes. Practical? No.

Dell doesn't sell SFF-to-LFF conversion kits, so your only choice is to cannibalize another R710 which is beside the point.

Comment: Right, as far as I remember there are no conversion kits. It would be necessary to find out all parts which needs to be exchanged and buy them as spare parts. That option seems to be costly (time consuming and expensive).